# Unable to load RWeka in R

Tags: java, r

I have installed RWeka package but i am unable to load it in R. Whenever I try to load the following appears[image]

Comment: Did you try doing the things that the error message says to do?

Comment: Yeah I've done that but Java is installed in programfiles(x86) of my c drive and r is installed in a different folder programfiles of the same drive. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `unloadNamespace('Rweka')` before `library(RWeka)`.

Comment: perhaps try re-installing the `rJava` package. Seems like it could be an issue with that.